# in vuepress how can I dynamically render some md content into cusomer theme (vue template)

Tags: vue.js, markdown, vuepress

in one .vue file(component) of the theme, I just want to dynamically render some md content as below in to the .vue template

md content:

```
::: slot aaa
# Here is slot aaa
:::
- A Paragraph
- Another Paragraph
::: slot bbb
Here is slot bbb
:::
```

and vue theme template is like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="theme-container">
    <Content slot-key="aaa" />
   <br/>=============
    <Content />
   <br/>=============
    <Content slot-key="bbb" />
    <br />
  </div>
</template>
```

And the md content I can get it from some back-end api, I want to dynamically render it in the page, how can I do it.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render markdown inside Vue component, you should write a vuepress plugin.

I used https://github.com/superbiger/vuepress-plugin-tabs source for reference.
You need to:

- define custom md container in markdown-it-container plugin, which should parse opening and closing container tags
- define your vue component in client.js
- define index.js for your plugin, which should export enhanceAppFiles and chainMarkdown
- add this plugin in .vuepress/config.js.

Comment: Hi Weisskopf
Thanks a lot for your response and guiding.
As I am newly to vue&vuepress, could you please help share more details or some example to me. many thanks.
And Another question,the vuepress-plugin-tabs, when we use it, we can write the example md code in our .md file, and then it will be render when page show,
But actually I want to dynamically to render some md contents in page, for example, in page we will call back-end api, and then get back some md contents, and I want these md contents dynamically displayed in page. I mean it should not be done at the compiling time.

Comment: Seems that I didn't quite get your question.
My answer (and vuepress-plugin-tabs) is about how to wrap static md in custom container, including Vue component.

But, as I can get, you need to render markdown dynamically inside Vue component.
Vuepress is a static site generator, markdown is parsed and rendered server-side.

Could you please be more specific about what kind of data do you want to get from back-end?
Do you need Vue component only for back-end interaction?

please look at this issue https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/452

Comment: Thank you so much, sir!
what I want to do is that, in page there is a editor, which can edit the page content, and the some of page content is actually from the md file, just like my md file, using the 
::: slot key1 :::
xxx
:::
And the editor default value is original md file content, and when I change the xxx to yyy, the page will automatically changed. But as you guiding, all the md file seems compiling at server side, in page when I generate some dynamical md content, and want to render it in page, I didn't know how to do it

Comment: In page, want the editor using slot to make the content can be distributed display in page, and also can use the markdown syntax.